# Merge 2 arrays based on a common element

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

So I have a Laravel controller that is pulling in 2 arrays.

Array 1:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null,
        "name":"The Darkroom",
        "description":"This is the room your parents warned you about",
        "image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1579662908513-50e1433a258a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80",
        "is_private":"0"
    },{
        "id":2,
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null,
        "name":"Smoking & Cigars",
        "description":"Time to light up and enjoy a cigar!",
        "image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1617850136763-06bc0a9a089c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80",
        "is_private":"0"
    },{
        "id":3,
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null,
        "name":"Humiliation",
        "description":"today is the day you are going to be exposed",
        "image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1571570261702-3d23956fa32e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2600&q=80",
        "is_private":"1"
    },{
        "id":4,
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null,
        "name":"Financial Domination",
        "description":"hand over your cash and say thank you Sir!",
        "image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1526304640581-d334cdbbf45e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=80",
        "is_private":"0"
    },{"id":5,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Pups & Handlers","description":"Woof, woof, bark, sit","image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1506939754500-f27bc71fccd4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=80","is_private":"1"}]
```

Array 2:

```
{"channels":{"presence-chat.1":{"user_count":1},"presence-chat.4":{"user_count":1}}}
```

Final Array should look like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":1
      "other data in the first array"
      "user_count": 1
   }
]
```

What I NEED to do inside my controller is merge the data together into a single array. So ideally, take the second array, match up the chat.ID with the ID of the first array and add in user_count to it... well you get what I mean.

I Have NEVER done this before so I have NO IDEA how best to go about this. Any help would be forever appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us how you want the final array to be as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this assumes that `presence-chat.4` means channel with the id of 4:

```
<?php

$json1 = '[{"id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"The Darkroom","description":"This is the room your parents warned you about","image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1579662908513-50e1433a258a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80","is_private":"0"},{"id":2,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Smoking & Cigars","description":"Time to light up and enjoy a cigar!","image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1617850136763-06bc0a9a089c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80","is_private":"0"},{"id":3,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Humiliation","description":"today is the day you are going to be exposed","image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1571570261702-3d23956fa32e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2600&q=80","is_private":"1"},{"id":4,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Financial Domination","description":"hand over your cash and say thank you Sir!","image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1526304640581-d334cdbbf45e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=80","is_private":"0"},{"id":5,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Pups & Handlers","description":"Woof, woof, bark, sit","image":"https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1506939754500-f27bc71fccd4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=80","is_private":"1"}]';
$json2 = '{"channels":{"presence-chat.1":{"user_count":1},"presence-chat.4":{"user_count":1}}}';

// convert the json into php arrays
$array1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$array2 = json_decode($json2, true);

// we extract the user_counts from the second array
// and make the index of a new array the channel id with value user_count
$channel_counts = [];
foreach ($array2['channels'] as $chan_name => $count) {
    $channel_id = explode('.', $chan_name)[1];
    $user_count = $count['user_count'];
    $channel_counts[$channel_id] = $user_count;
}

// we pass this array by reference as we are modifying it
foreach ($array1 as &$channel) {
    $id = $channel['id'];
    if (isset($channel_counts[$id]))
        $channel['user_count'] = $channel_counts[$id];
    else
        $channel['user_count'] = 0;
}
unset($channel);

$final_json = json_encode($array1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $final_json;
```

Which results in:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "name": "The Darkroom",
        "description": "This is the room your parents warned you about",
        "image": "https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1579662908513-50e1433a258a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80",
        "is_private": "0",
        "user_count": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "name": "Smoking & Cigars",
        "description": "Time to light up and enjoy a cigar!",
        "image": "https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1617850136763-06bc0a9a089c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=80",
        "is_private": "0",
        "user_count": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "name": "Humiliation",
        "description": "today is the day you are going to be exposed",
        "image": "https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1571570261702-3d23956fa32e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2600&q=80",
        "is_private": "1",
        "user_count": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "name": "Financial Domination",
        "description": "hand over your cash and say thank you Sir!",
        "image": "https:\/\/images.unsplash.com\/photo-1526304640581-d334cdbbf45e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=80",
        "is_private": "0",
        "user_count": 1
    }, ...snip
]
```

Comment: So this works perfectly fine as the code you gave but when I replace the json2 with the code I am using to grab the array it gives me the error "json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, stdClass given" but if I return the array it shows up just as I pasted it into my question. So yes you have the right answer I just dont know why it isnt working for me

Comment: How are you getting the JSON arrays?

Comment: in the case of the failing array.... it is using the pusher HTTP API - $pusherUserCount = $pusher->getChannels(['filter_by_prefix' => 'presence-', 'info' => 'user_count']) - As I said - if I return $pusherUserCount it shows the array just as you used it above

Comment: OK, try `$array2 = $pusher->getChannels(<snip>)->channels`, removing the `json_decode`

Comment: nope still didnt do it. Im going to mess around and see what is causing it. Like I said, I have tried it with the static arrays like you posted and it works, I have taken the array and converted it online to a PHP array and that works. So I am not sure what the difference is here.

Comment: How did you convert the result of `$pusher->getChannels` into JSON for the question?

Comment: I didn't convert it - it is returned as such. Literally if I were to type return $pusherUserCount - that is what is returned exactly as you see it. Also, he error I am getting is this... https://flareapp.io/share/q5Ye4oO5#F57L28 Just so you see what I see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238290/discussion-between-mulquin-and-arcticmediaryan).